# Merge Two Text Files Matching Values

Tags: regex, awk, match

I'm not 100% this can be done with AWK, if there is a better way than I wouldn't mind using that method.

I have two text files:

One file looks like this:

```
email:phone#:firstname
```

The second file looks like this:

```
phone#:lastname
```

Now I know that these two files come from the same source, but they were split up at one point.
Technically I could merge them back together by taking the `phone#` from the second file and matching it with the `phone#` in the first file. Once it finds a match then it can take `lastname` and append it to the appropriate line on the first file.
The end result would be

```
email:phone#:firstname:lastname
```

What would be the best way to do something like this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

with `join`

```
$ join -t: -12 -21 -o1.1,1.2,1.3,2.2 <(sort -t: -k2 file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: Will this still work if the second file is missing entries? I should have said that the second file is missing thousands of entries compared to the first file.

Comment: it can only match what is there are, the output will only have the fully matched records.